# Studio monitor placement in long room

Tags: studio

I have two KRK Rokit 8's and I am picking up a KRK 10s this week and I am curious about placement of my speakers.

[image]

I am guessing off to my left would be the best placement. But the room is so long with no acoustic treatment I am worried it will sound like garbage.

Comment: There's no need to "worry if" it will sound like garbage. In a long box-shaped room like your picture, that result is almost guaranteed unless you find a way to kill the slap-back echo from the end wall behind you. That echo will be making *everything* sound bad, not just your subwoofer.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what placement you have, without acoustic treatment you will never get the best experience. Remember, you can add very simple sound deadening for almost no cost - think soft furnishings, carpets, rugs and curtains. They will all help. We have a number of questions on [acoustics](/questions/tagged/acoustics) so have a look for others there. Your problem is going to be that you are in a corner, and as you pointed out, in a long straight room - and bass **loves** corners. I'd suggest at least some form of acoustic trap in all four corners, but especially in the corner you sit at.

Okay, now positioning for the sub is less critical than you might expect. Yes, you want it close enough that you don't suffer latency/phase issues, but if it's in front of you, to the left or to the right won't really matter. The wavelength is long enough that you will not experience it as a directional sound.

Comment: So directly behind the circle is a couch and on the end wall way back there is a wall rug thing that is super ugly and thick. That probably helps a lot. But I have no deadening stuff anywhere. I could probably pick up a couple corner deadening things for cheap.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally unscientific, it's just something I've known to work on occasion, if the room will take it.
My own room is set this way, though I'm in something closer to a cube with a sloped ceiling & I do have a decent amount of soft surface + bass traps behind the speakers & in the opposite corner.

I only really tried it out at home because my old [high budget] studio space was built around a V-shaped work area & I wanted to recreate that feel.
Sonically, it was just a happy accident.

Anyway... the idea is to turn yourself at 45° to the room & see how it goes.

(btw, this has to be my worst piece of Photoshopping ever;)

[image]

Comment: My wife would kill me if I did that lol

Comment: haha - sorry ;-) Maybe try it while she's out & see if it's worth fighting over?